# Where is the correct documentation for flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

The docs I can find for flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter [are here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/DateTimeFormatter.html).

In those docs, the examples show the use of an important method called `setDateTimeStyles()`.  However, there is no such documented method!  Same goes for `format()`.

I feel I'm missing something or am looking at dated/incomplete material (or am a complete idiot).  Where is the correct/best documentation?

---

PS: I'm finding I have this general problem (missing/incomplete docs) quite frequently and this question could *actually* be "Where is the 'correct' flex/actionscript documentation?  Or is it just bad?", but I'll be very specific (and non-inflammatory) to try and improve the odds of a clean answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you haven't chosen right target runtime in the documentation header of your link. Choose at least Flash Player 10.1 and AIR 2.5.

Comment: Aha!  So it *was* in the "I'm a complete idiot" category... this explains a lot of my apparent documentation issues.  And wow that is quite an assortment of documentation options.

Comment: Hehe. The problem is I felt the same some time ago. But finally found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking [at the wrong one](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Comment: nope - it was the runtimes/products selectors at the top that I had wrong.  fwiw, the one you point to just wraps flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter.